# Python Pandas extra commas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

im making a little work with csv and pandas and I must merge two CSV lists on one and delete the duplicates but the final output add extra commas to the last column and I don´t know why

I have two CSV lists like this:

```
  DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1   House        WiFi     CP 432     1
2   Farm         NONE     CP 345     1
3   House        Wifi     CP 315     1

  DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1   House        WiFi     CP 437     0
2   House        Wifi     CP 315     0
```

And when I merge the both the result is: (the number of "," is absolutely random)

```
ID  DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE,,,,,
1   House        WiFi     CP 432     1,,,,,,
2   Farm         NONE     CP 345     1,,,,
3   House        Wifi     CP 315     1,,,,,,
1   House        WiFi     CP 437     0,,,,,
```

This is my code:

```
with open("C:\\files\\20171412123920-1\\20171412123920-1Total.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f2:
    reader = csvCSV.reader(f)
    for row in reader:           
        merged.append(row)

with open("C:\\files\\20171412123920-1\\20171412123920-1.csv", "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    readerTotal = csvCSV.reader(f2)
    for row in readerTotal:
        merged.append(row) 



with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\Python\\20171412123920-1Comparacion.csv", "wb") as csvfile:

    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,dialect='excel', encoding='utf-8')
    spamwriter.writerow(["ID","DESCRIPTION","EXTRAS","ADDRESS","AVAILABLE"])
    for row in merged:

        spamwriter.writerow(row)

    df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\Python\\20171412123920-1Comparacion.csv", error_bad_lines=False) 

    df.to_string(index=False)
    df.drop_duplicates(['DESCRIPTION'], keep='first', inplace = True)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    df.set_index('ID', inplace = True)
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\Python\\201714121239201Comparacion.csv")
```

Comment: Huh... why are you opening the files with `"rt"`?

Comment: Really I´m new in this kind of stuff and I took it from a tutorial, the "rt" means "read in default text mode"

Comment: First of all, _always_ use `pd.read_csv` when loading CSVs into a dataframe. I think this problem is happening because of the manner in which you're reading those CSVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will merge both csv file in pandas dataframe. Then drop duplicate data from dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('first.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('second.csv')

frames = [df1, df2]
result=pd.concat(frames)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(result)
df5.drop_duplicates()

print(df5)
```